# Does F# Guideline recommend to declare module & type having the same name?

Tags: .net, module, f#, naming-conventions, record

After reading [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/), I don't see any comment whether I should declare module & its type to have the same name.

Usually my projects don't have any cyclic dependency, so I don't need to make a new module (e.g. `InfrastructureTypes` or `DomainTypes`) to put every types in one place.

For example, if I have a record type `System` and a bunch of its functions, should I put everything inside one module file? This is my attempt:

```
// System.fs
module System

type rec System =
    { name : string
      children : System list }

let init () = { name = ""; children = [] }

let addChild system child =
    { system with system.children = child :: system.children }

let removeChild system child =
    let rec removeChild children acc child =
        match children with
        | c :: children ->
            if c <> child then removeChild children (c :: acc) child
            else removeChild children acc child
        | [] -> List.rev acc

    let children = removeChild system.Children [] child
    { system with system.children = children }
```

Answer (score 10):

It is a common approach in the F# core library itself to have a module and type with the same name **at the same level** (as opposed to having the type inside the module like in your example). For example, there is a `List<'a>` type and a `List` module that contains the function that contains functions for working with it. Similarly with `Option`, `Set`, `Result` etc.

If you already had a type with a given name, there is an attribute you can add to to allow creating a module with the same name without a compiler error: `[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]`

However, since F# 4.1, this is implicit. So defining a module with the same name as the type just works, and the word `Module` will be at the end of the module name when the code is compiled.

```
type System =
    { name : string
      children : System list }

module System =
    let init () = { name = ""; children = [] }
```

I think all this implies that this can be a valid pattern to use in F#. Particularly when you have a good abstraction. You might want to look up "abstract data types" as I think they apply here.

Looking at the examples I've given above, this is normally more of a library-level pattern, but I've heard the argument that it can be applied to good effect in application code too. I can imagine that it could help you to think about and enforce abstraction boundaries and keep code organised.

Comment: @MiP - Do note that the type and the module are defined *at the same level*. In your example, your file starts with `module System`, which is shorthand for "the entire rest of this file is inside the module named `System`". Whereas the right way to go about it is to have both the type and the module defined at the same level. I can't make that clear enough in a comment box, so I'll post an answer expanding on this.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox By your solution, I need to make a master module to have these modules and types be at the same level, don't I?

Comment: @MiP In an FS file, yes, these need to go inside another module or a namespace.

Comment: Won't it bring another problem? For example, inside module `Computer`, there are a type `Kernel` and a type `Userland` with the same access level, which is clearly wrong. But I think your answer may be the best case though.

Comment: @MiP I'm not sure I follow. You can always have another module level if that's necessary to control access to the level required. I think you're better off using this pattern in a way that access control isn't important. E.g. if I make a `List` then I can put my private data in it. Other code that uses `List` can't necessarily access that data.

Comment: "and the word Module will be at the end of the module name when the code is compiled."
This is what I came for, thank you so much 